# I get this error! [ 'return' statement outside of function ]

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I was creating a form validator for a client and ran into this weird error *only* in Internet Explorer (Explorer) 7/8....

> 'return' outside of function, line 1, char 1

Of course, there was no code whatsoever on line 1. It was a simple commented statement. And there was nothing wring with it in any way. So I knew it was just a debug misdirection.

I have been pulling my hair out to understand what could be wrong here...

I have already ruled out the obvious: return statements in a loop, too many return statements in a single function, and any returns actually outside of a legitimate function definition.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: That usually means exactly what it says - that you have a return statement outside of any functions. Sample code would help...

Comment: Perhaps some source code would help us help you?

Comment: A code example would help. An error message is not sufficient to identify an error in your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a return statement to override the default behavior for my form and it was assigned to a property, *but* it was not placed inside an anonymous function!

I had a form element that was set up like this:

```
<form name="formname" onSubmit="javascript:validateForm(this);" action="javascript:return false;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

All I needed to change was the action property to this:

```
… action="javascript:function(){return false};"
```

It now works flawlessly!

Comment: `javascript:` URLs are evil; never use them, especially for `action`. If there is really nowhere useful to point the form for non-JS users, you can give it a useless action like `#`, and use `onsubmit="return false"` to stop it submitting (no `javascript:` prefix is needed on event handlers, which are not URLs; including it does nothing sensible). Or, if you don't need to associate script-only form fields with anywhere to submit them, you can just omit the form tag.

Comment: Sorry, but in some browsers the hash "#" generates an extra HTTP request, which should be avoided. Especially since Google is panicking over page load speed. This info is to let people know that using return ANYWHERE outside of a function will cause IE to throw an error. Any time you use "return", no matter which property it is in, it needs to be enclosed in a function: anonymous or otherwise.
By returning false you prevent the browser from performing its default behavior. It works in ALL browsers. Including the "javascript:" portion is simply good practices: It ensures proper code type'ing.

Comment: @bobince is right, don't use `javascript:`. Use `onsubmit="return validateForm(this);"` instead. `validateForm` just needs to return false to stop the form from being submitted. `onsubmit` already expects javascript, so no need for `javascript:`. So why not to leave the action empty? No need for a #.

Comment: exoboy's answer is a bit misleading.  The reason `action="javascript:function(){return false};"` blocks submitting the form is not because of the `return false` bit.  You could achieve the same blocking effect with `javascript:function(){return true};` or `javascript:function(){return 'pants'};` or `javascript:var foobar;` or `javascript:void(0);`.  Just wanted to point out that this code is a bit misleading.  It blocks the form submission because the javascript: code does nothing and returns nothing, not because it declares a function which would return false if it ran. Which it isn't (run)).

Comment: The code is not misleading. It is there for any browser that may not allow for an empty function, either nor or in the future. It is designed to be robust, not the smallest code possible...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when you're writing back end systems where the user is expected to have JavaScript enabled in order to use the system, I feel it's fine to use `javascript: href` tags, since use of the system requires JavaScript anyway.

In this case, there is nothing wrong with using `href="javascript:"`, is there?

Answer (score 1):

Check to *make sure* you are ***not*** *writing "var" in your function parameters*.

In many languages you must specify the type of the argument parameters. In JavaScript you do not have to.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on how omitting `var` helps with the OP's `return`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with a ModalPopupExtender. I had specified the following attribute:

```
OnOkScript="return false;"
```

Setting `OkOkScript=""` solved this issue for me.