# Return statement outside of function in jquery-1.5.2.min.js

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-7

I have a web page that works well in its development environment, which is VS2010 on Windows7 - 64 bit.  It also serves well from the IIS 7.5 to users on both 32 and 64 bit machines, using either IE7 or IE8 or IE9

But when we try to debug it on a WindowsXP machine (32 bit), using VS2010 with IE7, we get this error: "Return statement outside of function"

The error happens when we try to load this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Intranet/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you saying that this is a compilation, runtime, or browser error?

Comment: have you tried the newest version of jquery, or is there some reason you prefer 1.5.2?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly the same, but may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168713/i-get-this-error-return-statement-outside-of-function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pinpointing the error? You say including jQuery is the reason for the error, but isn't the error resulting from a combination of both HTML in the webpage and the jQuery plugin.

What happens when you have an almost empty HTML page with only the jQuery include script tag?